# Is it mandatory to use a relay driver for analog application?

Tags: relay

I am using a 5pin 6v relay in an analog circuit application. This is my first time to use a relay. I heard that there is a relay driver. Is it necessary to use a relay driver along with relay.
Its a 5 pin relay, 6v
And analog application, not a digital. 
Only 2 transistors included.
Automatic street light design using ldr and BC547 transistor.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it's not. Nobody can make you do anything. Now please read your question back to yourself and think, "How could anyone guess what I am talking about?" Then edit your question, explain what you are trying to do and add a schematic diagram. There's an 'add schematic' button in editor toolbar. You'll get help then.

Comment: Relays have been around for much longer than those newfangled relay drivers .In your simple application it would be easier and cheaper not to use a relay driver.

Answer (score 1):

A relay coil just needs some specified current for the relay to turn on.  Since the coil resistance is usually well known, this may also be specified as a voltage.  As long as you can produce that voltage at that current, you can drive the relay.

The rest of your question makes no sense, so is ignored.